# Why doesn't SpyPostProcessor implement getEarlyBeanReference() like AbstractAutoProxyCreator,it may cause circular reference Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-test

`AbstractAutoProxyCreator` will create the same proxy in `getEarlyBeanReference()` and `postProcessAfterInitialization()`

However, `MockitoPostProcessor#SpyPostProcessor` will create different proxy in either `getEarlyBeanReference()` or `postProcessAfterInitialization()`, it will cause circular reference exception in the following code:

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class MockitoTest {
    @SpyBean
    private DevComponent devComponent;
    @Autowired
    private TestComponent testComponent;
    @Test
    public void testMockito() {
        // ...
    }
}

@Component
public class DevComponent {
    @Autowired
    private TestComponent testComponent;
}

@Component
public class TestComponent {
    @Autowired
    private DevComponent devComponent;
}
```

such as:

> Error creating bean with name 'devComponent': Bean with name 'devComponent' has been injected into other beans [testComponent] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesForType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.

I am wondering why `MockitoPostProcessor#SpyPostProcessor` can't create proxy with cache key just like `AbstractAutoProxyCreator`,which will solve my problem.